# Count the number of selected rows in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How to count the number of selected rows in a DataGridView?

Let's say I highlighted 5 rows, how can I show it in message box?

Please help I'm using WinForms in C#!

Comment: I don;t know how to do it, I did it when I highlight 1 row only, but when I highlight multiple row it didn't work. 

firstCol = currentDatagrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
MessageBox.Show(firstCol );

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need to set `YourGridView.MultiSelect=true`; [MultiSelect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.multiselect.aspx)
When the MultiSelect property is set to true, multiple elements (cells, rows, or columns) can be selected in the DataGridView control. To select multiple elements, the user can hold down the CTRL key while clicking the elements to select. Consecutive elements can be selected by clicking the first element to select and then, while holding down the SHIFT key, clicking the last element to select.

then you can use SelectRows.Count property [SelectedRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows.aspx)

```
MessageBox.Show(yourDataGridView.SelectedRows.Count.ToString());
```

Comment: I don't know why but it's not working, the result is always 0 even when I highlighted all the rows in the datagridview

Comment: I see now why it didn't worked, the selectionmode of the datagridview must be set to FullRowSelect, however my selectionmode is in CellSelect, and it's not working with that selection mode, can I do it using mt prefer selectionmode?

Comment: MessageBox.Show(yourDataGridView.SelectedRows.Count.ToString()); add .ToString() and put this on double click event

Comment: @Ravi: it's now ok, I used SelectedCells instead. Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you use CellSelect, the SelectedRows count will be zero.  You need to iterate through the Cell collection and tally the different RowIndex values.  Note - if you have a large number of selected Cells, you can use DataGridView.AreAllCellsSelected(includeInvisibleCells: true) to find out if all are selected, in which case, DataGridView.Rows.Count will give you the row count.

Answer (score 0):

In VB.NET you can use a Lambda expression. Should be easy to translate to C:

```
SelectedRowCount = DataGridView1.SelectedCells.OfType(Of DataGridViewCell)().Select(Function(x) x.RowIndex).Distinct().Count()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your DataGridView allows Cell Select, you cannot directly get the count of rows selected.  Instead, you must iterate through the SelectedCells collection to count the number of distinct selected rows.
Here is a function that will return the count of currently selected rows based on the selected cells.

```
    public int DataGridViewRowCount(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        Dictionary<int, int> RowsFound = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        int nCells = dgv.GetCellCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
        int nRows = 0;
        if (dgv.AreAllCellsSelected(true))
            nRows = dgv.Rows.Count;
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < nCells; i++)
            {
                int rix = dgv.SelectedCells[i].RowIndex;
                if (!RowsFound.ContainsKey(rix))
                    RowsFound.Add(rix, rix);
            }
            nRows = RowsFound.Count;
        }
        return nRows;
    }
```

Note that for large numbers of rows (and thus large numbers of Selected Cells), the AreAllCellsSelected function will let you avoid the iteration and just return the number of Rows in the grid.  The argument to AreAllCellsSelected is a boolean whether to include invisible cells or not.

A Dictionary is used rather than a List to take advantage of the key indexing and performance when dealing with large numbers of selected cells.